# How do I add a component in the upper-left of a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jscrollpane

I have created a `JScrollPane` with a `RowHeaderView`, a `ColumnHeaderView` and a `ViewPortView`. I added JPanels in diffrent colors and noticed, that there is one cornor left, on the upper-left where you cant just add a `Component`. I wanted to ask, how it is possible to add a `Component` there.

Here a image. The area I mean is green:

[image]

And here my Code:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel0 = new JPanel();
        panel0.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 200));
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(panel0);
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(panel1);
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(panel2);
        scrollPane.setBackground(Color.green);

        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy. Use the method setCorner

```
scrollPane.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER, new JButton());
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank your. I searched the hole time for another method where "view" is in the name.